# Unity 3D how to make different things happen for triggers/collisions with different objects? C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, collision-detection

I have code for what happens when the enemy collides with the player using a rigid body on the player and clicking the is trigger on the collider in the inspector. When the player hits the enemy, the number of lives go down. I now have an empty game object (track) which has a rigid body and ticked the is trigger on the box collider, that one enemy moves toward. Once the enemy gets to the trigger, it is supposed to move back towards another empty game object (backTrack) to make it look like it is walking back again. At any point, if the player hits the enemy, the life count goes down by 1 and the enemy respawns at the start position. My problem is that I can't get it to distinguish between colliding with the player and track because at the minute, when the enemy hits track, it does what should be done if the player had hit the enemy and the enemy respawns at start position. Here is my code:

```
 private bool triggered = false;
 public GameObject track1;
 void moveBackTrack(){
     float move1 = moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
     transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards (transform.position, backTrack.position, move1);
 }
 void OnTriggerEnter(Collider col)
 {
     if (!triggered)
     {
         triggered = true;
         if (col.gameObject = track1) {
             moveBackTrack ();
         } else {
             Destroy (gameObject);
             print ("Collision Enter: " + col.name);
             GameManager.Instance.lives -= 1;
             GameManager.Instance.setLivesText ();
             GameManager.Instance.SpawnTrackEnemy ();
         }
     }
 }
```

Comment: You have a typo, performing an assignment rather than comparison: `col.gameObject = track1` should be `col.gameObject == track1`.

Comment: Thanks, my enemy is still not moving back towards the backTrack position, it is just standing still. Do you reckon this is a problem with the way I am phrasing my if statement or a problem with my moveBackTrack() method? @Serlite

Comment: If your enemy is spawned immediately in a collision with your track, the [OnTriggerEnter event may not occur](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/505589/trigger-or-colission-not-work-if-inside-volume.html). Also note that no matter what, OnTriggerEnter will only occur once, so at most `moveBackTrack()` will only be called once. Use `OnTriggerStay` if you need it to be fired every physics loop.

Comment: you're looking for the **LAYER** system in Unity.  in practice (except on the most trivial demo scenes) you have to use physics layers **every time and always** in game engines.  Click to **Edit, Project Settings, Physics** (or Physics 2D).  Notice the "triangle chart" of interactions.  read and learn about Layers on the various unity tutorials.  they have many perfect tutorials https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z3QfdjoksfE

Answer (score 1):

Set a tag ID for the player and enemy objects, then subscribe to the OnCollisionenter event of your track. This will fire when any collision occurs between another object and the collider of your track object.

```
void OnCollisionEnter(Collision col){
    GameObject collidedWith = col.gameObject;
    if(collidedWith.tag == "PlayerTagName"){
        //do player collided logic here
    }
    else if(collidedWith.tag == "EnemyTagName"){
        //do enemy collided logic here
    }
}
```

By handling each object by its Tag name individually, you can better maintain your code, making it easier to code to each separate condition. I recommend setting up a similar OnCollissionEnter handler for your player and enemies as well, depending on how many conditions might occur in the logic of your game.

Comment: Thanks for your help, my enemy is hitting the track trigger now and then nothing is happening. Do you think there is something wrong with my moveBackTrack() method?

Comment: Here's what I need you to do. ABUSE the print method. Print to the console before and after moveBackTrack, print what variable values should be, and print when you think they should be changing. The best I can do to help you here is to convince you that you can find out whats going on here simply by examining the components of your application with a magnifying glass. You are playing detective here. And when you can pinpoint where things are going wrong exactly, we can better help you find out why they are going wrong.

Comment: The variables used in this are the enemy position, the enemy speed, the track position, the backTrack position and the trigger event. All these are the same before and after the method is called, and it is recognizing the trigger for the track. Can't think of anything else to print, but also the trigger for the player is no longer recognized once it hits the track trigger whether I use onTriggerEnter or onTriggerStay

Comment: Have you printed inside the method to ensure it is being called properly?

Comment: It is trying to call the move back method but because in my update bit I have my move forward method, they are conflicting with each other.

Comment: Then it sounds like we have resolved the issue of how to make different things happen with triggers and collisions in different objects, and now we're onto new areas. Please mark this as answered so others don't get confused, and I will gladly help you with any other problems.

Comment: I strongly recommend this book if you're just starting out in unity. There are many great examples of how to better organize the behaviour of your application so that these conflicts are much less frequent and FAR easier to detect and resolve. http://www.amazon.com/Introduction-Game-Design-Prototyping-Development/dp/0321933168/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1459200274&sr=8-1&keywords=introduction+to+game+design+prototyping+and+development

Comment: Done. I have it almost sorted - right now, spawn a new enemy that moves in the opposite direction under a new tag and this works well for movement purposes. After it hits the track trigger, and respawns and begins to move back towards the next track position, it won't recognize the player at all. As in the trigger function for the respawned enemy won't work at all

Comment: I'm glad you're getting it sorted out.